# Case statement causing duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've successfully built messaging functionality into my application, I have a small issue which I need assistance on, when I send an email to another user I insert this message into the database, the column ReadDate for this row will be null due to it being new, when I read this message from the UI the ReadDate column will then be populated with today's date.

Now my issue is this, given the below query, which returns emails inside someones inbox where ReceipientId = @UserId passed in. :

```
 Select p.Id [SenderId], p.Username, count(mr.RecipientId) [TotalMessages], up.PhotoId,
        CASE
            WHEN mr.ReadDate is null then 1 -- New message
            ELSE 0 -- Message has been read
        END AS NewMessage,
 p.LastLoggedIn, p.LoggedIn
 FROM [User].[User_Profile] p
 JOIN [MailBox].[Message] m on p.Id = m.SenderId
 JOIN [MailBox].[MessageRecipient] mr on m.Id = mr.MessageId
 LEFT JOIN [User].[User_Photos] up on p.Id = up.UserId
 where up.isProfilePic = 1 and mr.RecipientId = @UserId and mr.DeletedDate is null
 GROUP BY p.id, p.Username, mr.RecipientId, up.PhotoId, p.LastLoggedIn, p.LoggedIn,
 CASE
     WHEN mr.ReadDate is null then 1 -- New message
     ELSE 0 -- Message has been read
 END;
```

When I execute this I get returned the following:

[image]

As you can see its the same user, difference being I have a NewMessage i.e 1  which is causing this user to appear twice, If I remove the case statement within my query then I get the one row but I wouldn't know if I have a new message.  I'm having trouble trying to get this query to return only 1 row and state 1 or 0 for NewMessage depending on if I have a new message or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our conversation in the comments I think this will give you the result you are looking for:

```
Select p.Id [SenderId], 
       p.Username, 
       count(mr.RecipientId) [TotalMessages], 
       count(case when mr.ReadDate is null then 1 end) As [NewMessages],
       up.PhotoId, 
       p.LastLoggedIn, 
       p.LoggedIn
 FROM [User].[User_Profile] p
 JOIN [MailBox].[Message] m on p.Id = m.SenderId
 JOIN [MailBox].[MessageRecipient] mr on m.Id = mr.MessageId
 LEFT JOIN [User].[User_Photos] up on p.Id = up.UserId and up.isProfilePic = 1 
 where mr.RecipientId = @UserId and mr.DeletedDate is null
 GROUP BY p.id, 
          p.Username, 
          mr.RecipientId, 
          up.PhotoId, 
          p.LastLoggedIn, 
          p.LoggedIn
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet, I have just tried this but it still gives me the same result.

Comment: Now that I think about it, why do you need the group by? does TotalMessages represent the total number of messages inside the mailbox?

Comment: correct yes it does, I want the group by purely because I want to group all messages by that one user instead of showing an individual entry for every time that person emails another person

Comment: but the TotalMessages is different between the 2 rows. It seems lime female2 sent 7 messages the receipient alreary saw, and just 1 new message. you want to get a single row for all messages by the same sender, with an indication if there is at least one new message in a single row for each sender, right?

Comment: That's correct yes, so if we look at the picture example I provided what I want is for it to say TotalMessages: 8  NewMessage: 1

Comment: Sorry last question, I have a column called SentDate how can I select the most recent date? regardless if we have a un-read email or not?

Comment: add to the select clause `max(SentDate)`